# MongoDB rename boundary values for output

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this query to display people in certain age groups.

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {
      $bucket: {
        groupBy: "$age",
        boundaries: [ 0, 10, 20,  30, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ],
        default: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        output: {
          "count": { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
enter code here
```

which produces following output:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 10, "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 20, "count" : 6 }
{ "_id" : 30, "count" : 9 }
```

I want to display it as

```
{ "_id" : 0, "count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 10, "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 20, "count" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ">30", "count" : 9 }
```

How can I make it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hacky way this make this happen, you'll have to add a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)
stage and specify the logic you want, like so:

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {
        $bucket: {
            groupBy: "$age",
            boundaries: [ 0, 10, 20,  30, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ],
            default: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
            output: {
                "count": { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ['$_id', 30]}, '>30', '$_id']
            },
            count: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is produces the output as 
{ "count" : 5, "_id" : 0 }
{ "count" : 10, "_id" : 10}
{ "count" : 6, "_id" : 20}
{ "count" : 9, "_id" : ">30" }

is there a way to reverse? so that it will be like { "_id" : ">30", "count" : 9}.

Comment: $project: {
            _id: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ['$_id', 30]}, '>30', '$_id']
            },
            "count" : '$count'
        }

this worked like a charm, thank you again Tom